# Expanding mySQL query to include more content

Tags: sql, mysql, drupal

I have a MySQL query that selects content created by friends of the current user and lists that content in reverse chronological order.

```
    SELECT node.nid AS nid,
   node.created AS node_created
 FROM node node 
 LEFT JOIN user_relationships user_relationships ON node.uid = user_relationships.requestee_id
 LEFT JOIN users users_user_relationships ON user_relationships.requestee_id = users_user_relationships.uid
 WHERE (node.status <> 0) AND (node.type in ('drigg', 'blog_post')) AND (user_relationships.requester_id = 1)
   ORDER BY node_created DESC
```

How do I "expand" this query so it lists comments in addition to nodes?

here's the structure of the comment table:

- cid            (comment ID)
- uid            (ID of user who posted comment)
- timestamp      (uses same UNIX date
  format as the "node created" column
  from the node table up above)

So right now the query grabs all the "nodes" written by people who are buddies with the current user.  I want it to also grab all the comments written by people who are buddies with the current user.  Then I want to list these nodes and comments in DESC order based on the date they were created.

It appears I need to add more stuff to my select statement, but I'm not sure what.

Comment: You are only selecting two columns (node.nid, node.created). Am I right that you want to increase this select to three columns: (node_id, comment_id, created) where for each row, only one of (node_id, comment_id) is set? What about other data associated with the node and comment, such as the text body? Shouldn't you fetch that too? Or are you fetching that in a separate query?

Comment: We can fetch that stuff, too.  I was just trying to keep my question simple.  I figured if I can get even just a list of node and comment IDs in reverse chrono order, then I can figure out how to turn those into full stories and comments.  Didn't want to ask something so tricky that no one answers it.

Comment: @bflora: I'm glad to hear that. I was worried that you were going to only return all the ids, then get the rest of the data by looping and making new queries. Keeping the question simple is a good thing, but I'm always curious to know a little more about the background behind the question to make sure there isn't an easier way to solve the problem, and that's why I asked.

Comment: @bflora: I'd also be tempted to solve this by making two separate ordered queries (one for nodes, and one for comments) and merging the results on the client. Have you considered if such an approach is workable? It might be simpler and cleaner - you can reuse your existing class for comments and nodes, and you won't have tons of NULLs in the result set. The disadvantage of course is the extra roundtrip to the server.

Comment: Well, that's a bit beyond me, unfortunately.  At the moment, I'm gambling that I'm going to be able to figure out how to add pagination and other Drupal-y bits to this. Is it kosher to ask if you want to jump on IRC to work on this a bit more?

Comment: If you want to have paging without a lot of effort, probably best to stick with one query.

Comment: @bflora: For the comments, do you also want the nodeid the comment belongs to as well as the commentid, even if the nodeid doesn't belong to the user?

Comment: Sure.  That way I can grab the title of the node and the viewer can click over to see the story where his buddy was commenting.

Comment: I'd suggest that you try to write each of the queries (one for nodes, one for comments) separately first, and test them. Once you have them working, combine them into one query with a 'UNION ALL' like I showed in my answer. If you post the two separate queries here (you already posted one of them) it will be easy for me or someone else to add the UNION ALL keyword and combine the two queries.

Comment: Here's the comments one.  Returns latest comments from a user's buddies.

SELECT comments.cid AS cid,
   comments.timestamp AS comment_created
   comments.nid AS comment_nid
   comments.uid AS comment_uid
   comments.name AS comment_name
   comments.comment AS comment_comment
 FROM comments comments 
 LEFT JOIN user_relationships user_relationships ON node.uid = user_relationships.requestee_id
 LEFT JOIN users users_user_relationships ON user_relationships.requestee_id = users_user_relationships.uid
 WHERE (node.status <> 0) AND (user_relationships.requester_id = 1)
   ORDER BY timestamp DESC

Answer (score 1):

You can use a UNION ALL to combine the results from the two queries:

```
SELECT nodeid, commentid, created FROM (
    SELECT node.nid AS nodeid, NULL as commentid, node.created AS created
    FROM node node 
    LEFT JOIN user_relationships user_relationships ON node.uid = user_relationships.requestee_id
    LEFT JOIN users users_user_relationships ON user_relationships.requestee_id = users_user_relationships.uid
    WHERE (node.status <> 0) AND (node.type in ('drigg', 'blog_post')) AND (user_relationships.requester_id = 1)
    UNION ALL
    SELECT NULL as nodeid, comment.cid AS commentid, comment.timestamp AS created
    FROM node node 
    LEFT JOIN user_relationships user_relationships ON node.uid = user_relationships.requestee_id
    LEFT JOIN users users_user_relationships ON user_relationships.requestee_id = users_user_relationships.uid
    WHERE (node.status <> 0) AND (node.type in ('drigg', 'blog_post')) AND (user_relationships.requester_id = 1)
)
ORDER BY created DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

> So right now the query grabs all the "nodes" written by people who are buddies with the current user. I want it to also grab all the comments written by people who are buddies with the current user. Then I want to list these nodes and comments in DESC order based on the date they were created.

Use:

```
   SELECT n.nid,
          COALESCE(c.timestamp, n.created) AS coalesced_timestamp,
          c.comment
     FROM NODE n
LEFT JOIN USER_RELATIONSHIPS ur ON ur.requestee_id = n.uid
LEFT JOIN USERS u ON u.uid = ur.requestee_id
LEFT JOIN COMMENT c ON c.uid = u.uid
                   AND c.nid = n.nid
    WHERE n.status <> 0 
      AND n.type in ('drigg', 'blog_post') 
      AND ur.requester_id = 1
 ORDER BY coalesced_timestamp DESC
```

That's [based on the ERD listed here](http://drupal.org/files/issues/Drupal5RC1_Database_0.png).

It doesn't make much sense to have table aliases that are the same, or longer than the table name itself.

Comment: Good point with the unnecessary table aliases. If I understand your query though I think it would only list comments that the user made on nodes that they also created. Perhaps bflora also wants comments made by a user on nodes that they did not create? I don't know drupal, so I don't know if this is even possible.

Comment: Mark is correct. I want to "decouple" comments from nodes in this query. I want a list of the latest comments and nodes created by the current user's buddies.  This way the user can see what his buddies have been posting and commenting on and can find new stuff.  After poking around in Drupal's Views module, it appears it's not able to return a list of comments and nodes in the same query, hence rolling a custom query.  Drupal's great at letting you list nodes.  I jsut wish I could include comments, removed from their context, in the same query.

Comment: Updated based on clarifications.